# what's the relation between functional and norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the Banach space $L^p(\mu)$,$1\leq p<\infty$.For any $f\in L^p$,we have $$||f||_p=\left(\int_X |f|^pd\mu\right)^{1/p}<\infty.$$ On the other hand,by Riesz Representative Theorem,we have $$\Lambda f=\int_X fd\mu.$$ So what's the relation between them?

For an application,for $1\leq p<\infty$,let $L^p=L^p(-\pi,\pi)$ with respect to Lebesgue measure .And in this $L^p$, $f_n(t)=e^{int},-\pi\leq t\leq\pi$.I want to claim that $f_n$ converges to $0$ weakly but not strongly.How do I start?

Comment: Do you mean convergence in $L^{p,\infty}$ by "weakly convergent"?

Comment: Yes,but $p<\infty$.Since $||f_n||_p=(2\pi)^{1/p}$,it is clear that $f_n$ do not converge to $0$ strongly.And $\Lambda f_n=0$,thus the weak convergenct is also clear,is it right?

Comment: With the distribution funciton $d_f(t)$ I see, that weakly convergent is per definition
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{t>0} t (d_{e^{in\cdot}}(t))^{\frac{1}{p}} = 0$$
So maybe start by trying to figure out $d_{e^{in\cdot}}(t)$ for fixed $n$. A first note: $|e^{in\cdot}| = 1$, so $d_{e^{in\cdot}}(t) = 0 \quad \forall t \geq 1$.

Comment: Why not just ask the second part of the question, rather than the vague "what is the relation between..." which is not a well-formed question?

Comment: Oh,I haven't any background of distribution function,so I can't understand what's your meaning.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews.I think whether there are some relations between them,especially when we consider the weak and strong convergence.

Comment: For the second part, do it first in $L^2$ to gain some intuition. But the general case is not hard: the $L^p$-norms of $e^{inx}$ do not converge to $0$ so $e^{inx}$ cannot converge to $0$ strongly. But they converge weakly to zero, by using the definition of weak convergence in $L^p$ and the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: @brom.Yes,that's what I am looking for.Thank you.

Comment: Note, weak convergence is another form of convergence. My suggested form of weak convergence, was convergence in the weak $L^p$-space ($L^{p,\infty}$) which does not apply (as shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f \in L^p(\mu)$ and $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$, then $f$ induces a linear functional $F: L^q(\mu) \to \mathbb{C}$ by setting
$$F(g) = \int \! fg \, d\mu.$$
The relation between $f$ and $F$ is that $\|F\| = \|f\|_p$. One of the Riesz Representation Theorems states that *every* linear functional on $L^q(\mu)$ is of this form. Although this is not the one you quoted in your post, I think you may have meant this one (the one you quote represents the linear functionals on the space of continuous functions as regular Borel measures).

Now to the second part of the question. Let $f_n(x) = e^{inx}$. You want to show that $f_n$ converges weakly, but not strongly, to $f = 0$ in $L^p(-\pi, \pi)$. To see that $f_n$ does not converge strongly to $0$ note that
$$\|f_n\|_p =\left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi \! |f_n|^p \, dx \right)^{1/p} = \left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi \! 1 \, dx \right)^{1/p} = (2\pi)^{1/p}$$
for every $n$. But if $f_n$ converges strongly to $f = 0$, then we would have $\|f_n\|_p \to 0$. Hence $f_n$ does not converge strongly to $f$.

Now we want to show that $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$ in $L^p(-\pi,\pi)$. What exactly does that mean? It means that for every linear functional $F$ on $L^p(\pi, \pi)$ we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F(f_n) = 0.$$
Now we use the Riesz Theorem to see that this actually means that for all $g \in L^q(-\pi, \pi)$ we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \! g(x) f_n(x) \, dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \! g(x) e^{inx} \, dx= 0.$$
Now we instantly recognize that second term is exactly the $-n$-th Fourier coefficient $\hat{g}(-n)$ of $g$ so we want to prove
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \hat{g}(-n) = 0.$$
But now we simply notice that since $(-\pi, \pi)$ has finite measure we also have $g \in L^1(-\pi, \pi)$ and apply the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma which asserts exactly the truth of this last statement. I hope this clears up some of your confusion.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$ ($q$ is the conjugate Hölder exponent)

Comment: By Riesz representative theorem,$\Lambda f_n=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}f_n(t)dt=0$.It happens $\Lambda f_n=0$!So what confuses me is the representation of the functional on a particular space.Your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After considering my arguments, I conclude that with
$$d_f(t) := \lambda\{x : |f(x)| > t \}, \quad \lVert f \rVert_{p,\infty} = \sup_{t>0} t (d_f(t))^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
we have
$$d_{e^{in\cdot}}(t) = \lambda(-\pi,\pi)\chi_{[0,1)}(t) = 2\pi \chi_{[0,1)}(t)$$
and thus
$$\lVert e^{in\cdot} \rVert_{p,\infty} = \sup_{1>t>0}(2\pi)^{\frac{1}{p}} t = (2\pi)^{\frac{1}{p}} \neq 0$$
So your claim is false. $(e^{in\cdot})_n$ does not converge weakly to $0$.

Comment: Also think you for your caution of weak $L^p$-space.It seems a new concept to me.But only having some sense on distribution function can I understand what you have said.